# Sitecore 8 throwing null exception when Datasource item does not exist

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I am facing the below problem and can't find out how to get around to it.

1. I have a rendering and its datasource is pointing to an item in the tree.
2. I publish the rendering but I don't publish the referenced item.
3. While viewing the page I get an error. [attached is the screen shot of the error i am getting]

[image]

I am using glass mapper.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which version of Glass Mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate jammykam's answer, you can do something like the code below which I have found in this [blog](http://sitecorepromenade.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/passing-invalid-id-in-rendering.html)

Config Patch:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <mvc .getrenderer="">
        <processor patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetViewRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc']" type="Namespace.To.Sitecore.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetViewRendererWithItemValidation, Library">
        </processor>
      </mvc>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
public class GetViewRendererWithItemValidation : GetViewRenderer
{        `
    protected override Renderer GetRenderer(Rendering rendering, GetRendererArgs args)
    {           
        var viewRenderer = base.GetRenderer(rendering, args) as ViewRenderer;
        if (viewRenderer == null)
            return null;

        // Ignore item check when in page editor
        // Also this will break if the item for the datasource has been deleted without removing the link.
        if (Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor || Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing)
            return viewRenderer;

        // Override renderer to null when there is an unpublished item refererenced by underlying view
        return viewRenderer.Rendering.Item != null && viewRenderer.Rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem != null
            ? viewRenderer
            : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to tap into the `mvc.getRenderer` pipeline and validate the datasource actually exists, otherwise fallback gracefully.

There are a number of solutions already proposed for this and is a known "issue", although it is not a Glass specific issue:

- [Sitecore - automated validation of MVC rendering DataSource](http://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-automated-validation-of-mvc-rendering-datasource)
- [Rendering Exception Handling - The Right Way](http://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2015/10/23/Rendering-Exception-Handling-The-Right-Way/)
- [Robust MVC Rendering Exception Handler](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/june/mvc-rendering-exception-handler.aspx)
- [HANDLING RENDERING EXCEPTIONS IN MVC SOLUTIONS WITH THE SITECORE ASP.NET CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/09/Handling-Rendering-Exceptions-in-MVC-Solutions-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)

All these solutions check if the datasource item exists, in normal mode the error is swallowed but in Page Editor mode a warning is displayed to the editors so show the fact that datasource needs to be set in cases where none has been selected.

It was also [raised as an issue](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/163) in Glass Mapper with a similar solution.